# What does 'out of shit' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

Ok, I see this definition https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=out%20of%20shit: back to reality.

> Never give up, I'ma make elixir out of shit

Then this line means he will make a good music when he wakes up after sleeping/tripping? I just want to hear your thoughts.

Source: https://genius.com/Ghostemane-polaris-annotated

Comment: You need to parse that sentence differently...they're "making elixer out of shit"...like making gold from dirt or wine from water.  They're taking something of little value and making something more valuable "out of it".  In other words, "with it".

Comment: Where is that quote from? Please cite your source.

Comment: @Laurel, I added a source

Answer (score -1):

### "Shit" is standing in for "stuff" but with the added connotation that the stuff is of little to no importance/value.